# Try to check if Tree is Maximum Heap

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, pseudocode

First i insert the Heap into an Array (according to Level order (aka Breadth first) traversal),
and now i check the array

```
 For i = 1 to Len(Array) do:
         IF 2 * i smaller than Len(Array):
            IF Array[i] smaller than Array[2i] OR Array[i] larger than  Array[2i+1]:
                 Return false
         Else if 2 * i larger than Len(Array):
            Return True
```

But my problem is the algorithm work only if the tree is a complete binary tree,if not hot can i improve my code??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Array[i] larger than  Array[2i+1]
```

Shouldn't that check be the opposite:

```
Array[i] smaller than  Array[2i+1]
```

I think you have a bug there.

Also, you have other issues.

E.g. do "return true" after the loop is done.

Try this pseudo-code:

```
For i = 1 to Len(Array) do:
BEGIN

IF 2 * i + 1 <= Len(Array)
         IF ( Array[i] smaller than Array[2i] ) OR ( Array[i] smaller than Array[2i+1]):
                 Return false
ELSE IF 2 * i <= Len(Array):
         IF Array[i] smaller than Array[2i]:
                 Return false
ELSE:
    break // break from the loop 

END

RETURN TRUE;
```

Comment: ,thanks i will fixed the first problem,but in your algorithm why you are not checked first if 2*i<=len(array)?

Comment: I probably would've removed that `ELSE` and `Array[i] smaller than Array[2i]` from the first inner if-statement. Also, having those if-statements within if-statements here is probably a bit pointless as you can just put an `AND` between the two conditions instead, but this would assume short-circuiting, so this way might be clearer.

Comment: Change that to `For i = 1 to Len(Array)/2`. You know that if `i >= Len(Array)/2)`, then `2*i + 1` is going to exceed `Len(Array)`, so there's no need to go beyond that.

Comment: @Dukeling OK, I get your point but that's a matter of some style. This one I find more explicit.

Comment: @Jim Mischel OK, right, I added a break in the loop, it is cleaner this way and I don't need to calculate when exactly to stop (and consider when Len is even/odd etc.).

Comment: @peter.petrov It would do exactly the same thing as your code does now, just with less code.

Comment: Got it now (right after posting the comment), so I just changed my comment.

Comment: @Evyatar Elmaliah "but in your algorithm why you are not checked first if 2*i<=len(array)" because if 2*i + 1 <= len this implies that 2*i <= len but the reverse is not true (think what happens in the boundary case when 2*i==len, and you will understand why I did it this way)

Answer (score 2):

You can found the left child with: i*2 + 1 and the right one with i*2 + 2 (if you start with i = 0).

```
for(i=0; i< length; i++)
{
  if((i*2+1) < length)
    if(heap[i*2+1] > heap[i])
      return false;

  if((i*2+2) < length)
    if(heap[i*2+2] > heap[i])
      return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: His array is 1-based, not 0-based I think. So the indexing is not the problem in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah I had just edited. It depends on his problem. Maybe he has not this constraint.

Comment: Seems your code confirms my guess that he has a bug there. Your code seems correct with respect to that.

Comment: See these IF / ELSE IF checks I am doing in the loop. You don't have them and I think you should have them in your code.

Comment: You are right, but I think that you do not have to put an 'else if', but just an 'if' because otherwise you could skip the second control. It depends on the semantic of you pseudo code though.

Comment: @Max,yes,my array is 1-based but its not the problem,the problem is the algorithm work only if the tree is a complete binary tree,you have an idea to fix it?

Comment: @Evyatar Elmaliah your code with my fixes is fine, it does not work for complete trees only but for all trees/arrays which we want to check for having the heap property

Comment: I am missing something here. If you have the length of the heap, should not it suffice to know when to stop the function without segmentation faults? Maybe for not complete tree you mean a tree that is missing values of his children in some level before the last? For that you have to choose a dummy value that indicates that it contains no child. For instance the value -1.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work if your array is based at index 1. That is, the [0]th index of the array does not contain the heap data, but is a placeholder. This method is sometimes used to create consistency with other sorting methods. Of course this could (and probably should) be implemented as a separate function.

```
for (int i = 1; i < (array.size() - 1); i++)
{
    if ((2 * i) + 1 <= array.size() - 1)          // if it has two children
    {
        if ((array[i] < array[2 * i]) || (array[i] < array[(2 * i) + 1]))
        {
            cout << "RETURNING FALSE" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    else if ((2 * i) <= array.size() - 1)         //if it has only one child  
    {
        if (array[i] < (array[(2 * i)]))
        {
            cout << "RETURNING FALSE2" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
}
cout << "IS A VALID HEAP.";
```